# Make parameter accessible by two actions in same way. params[:user][:form]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

#### Route:

edit action:
`/profiles/edit?form=address`

### Controller

```
before_action :form_type, only: %i[edit update]

def edit
end

def update
end

def form_type
     @form_type = params[:form] || params[:user][:form]
end
```

#### View

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user, url: profiles_path, wrapper: :input_group  do |f| %>
                <%= render_user_form(f, @form_type, self) %>
                <%= f.input :form, as: :hidden , :input_html => {value: @form_type} %>
                <div class="action">
                  <%= f.submit 'Update', class: ''%>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

When my parameters get passed to the controller, on the edit page, it passes through to params[:form], but for the update action it's accessible as params[:user][:form]. How do I get the edit page to also make the param accessible the same way as.. params[:user][:form].

I prefer to access as params[:user][:form], not as params[:form], for both actions, if possible.

Comment: The view you posted: is that the exact same for both #edit and #new? If not, please post both views.

Comment: Why pass `@form_type` to the partial? Just add it as a hidden field in the view.

Comment: There is no new action.

Comment: Form type is passed to the helper to help show the fields to update.

Comment: The fields display differently based on the form type

Comment: #edit is GET, #update is POST. How are you passing the `[:form]` param to the edit page?

Comment: See above url.  ?form=address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails (technically its Rack) nests inputs by the name attribute. So if you submit this form:

```
<form action="/somepath">
  <input name="foo" value="1" type/>
  <input name="bar[baz]" value="2" type/>
  <input name="moo[woo]" value="3"/>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

You would get the following params hash:

```
{ 
   foo: 1,
   bar: {
     baz: 2
   },
   moo: {
     woo: 3
   }
}
```

The raw parameters would look like:

```
foo=1&bar[baz]=2&moo[woo]=3
```

Rack treats these parameters the same way regardless if they are sent via the query string or in the form body.

So if you want to pass the key as `params[:user][:form]` in the query you want the url `/profiles/edit?user[form]=address`.

You can create a link by:

```
# Im just guessing the name of the helper
<%= link_to 'Edit', profiles_edit_path(user: { form: 'address' }) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I believe the `form`-type (address, I wonder what the other options are? profile, account, details ...) is not saved to the user, it is just a parameter you need on the controller side to know which part of the profile to update (imho it would not make sense to save the `form` parameter in the profile). So I am guessing you have some kind of multi-page form and solve it this way.

Well the easiest way imho, is to keep your url as is, and in your form write:

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user, url: profiles_path, wrapper: :input_group  do |f| %>
  <%= render_user_form(f, @form_type, self) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :form, @form_type %>
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit 'Update', class: ''%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This will add a hidden field, but not in the context of the user, so it will just be `params[:form]`. This I believe will be more correct.

Secondly, I have some small remarks with regards to your approach:

- why not use `profile` singular? It is imho your intention to send the user to their profile (and there is only one, right?). In your routes you can write `resource :profile`. See documentation for [singular resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) (which coincidentally uses the profile example)
- why not use nested resources for the different parts of a profile: this could also more naturally map to your data-model (or maybe it should): a user has an address (and probably more than one --a current, a delivery, invoicing, ...), has extra info, and then your urls would look like `profile/address/edit` (and then you would not have to handle the `render_user_form` with a form-type so akwardly).

Comment: Very good point about using nested routes. That would most likely be a much better design

Answer (score 0):

***Updated with @Max's corrections***

Your issue is with how you are passing the param to the `edit` controller action (which is a GET request) vs. how the form passes params to the `update` controller action (which is a POST request, so the form values are in the request body).

With GET requests, everything you pass past the `?` gets "parameterized".

When you pass `/profiles/edit?form=address` then `params[:form]` is available.

When your form submits, the form builder creates nested inputs by naming them with a `model_name[attribute]` convention.

#### To achieve what you asked, you can just do `/profiles/edit?user[form]=address`

IMHO, you should do `params[:form]` in both contexts instead of `params[:user][:form]`.

You can get `params[:form]` in your partial by not using the `simple_form` helpers.

Try a standard [text_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) instead of a `f.field` tag. Make sure to set the HTML name  value as `form`:

`text_field_tag 'form' @form_type`

Then when you render the view, you should see something like this:

**what you have:**
`<input id="user_form" name="user[form]" type="text" />`

**what you want:**
`<input id="form" name="form" type="text" />`

Also, I'd suggest switching your param to `form_type` since SimpleForm might use `#user_form` as the ID of the form (`<form id="user_form" ...>`) and that would make any Javascript lookups by ID get conflicty.

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect. "When your form submits, it's doing so in the context of a User, so all the User params are nested under user (hence simple_form_for User)." - just no. The form builder creates nested inputs by naming them `model_name[attribute]`. If you have multiple inputs the query string will look like `?user[name]=bob&user[email]=bob@example.com` but it can contain multiple other parameters like for example `?user[name]=bob&form_type=address&foo=bar`.

Comment: For POST request its the same except passed in the request body.

Comment: "You could try doing something like /profiles/edit?user=[form=address] but I bet probably isn't allowed and you could spend hours trying to make a URL look like a POST form submission.". `/profiles/edit?user[form]=address`. Not very hard at all.